# undefined method `login' for #<Employee::ActiveRecord_Relation*>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting below error when I try to access 'login' method of object class in views.

```
undefined method `login' for #<Employee::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xb2ea0800>
```

This is what I write in views:

```
<%= form_for :employees, url: 'employees/login' do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :login %>
<% end %>
```

This is how my model look like:

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
end
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: you should use the form for a single object, not for multiple objects try, `@employee` instead of `employees`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your controller as,

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @employees = Employee.all
  end

  def new
    @employee = Employee.new
  end
end
```

Now the view can be,

```
<%= form_for @employee, url: 'employees/login' do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :login %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: glad to help you. Have a good day .By the  way, my name is sravan, ;-).

Comment: ohh sorry,you too